# Cannot import class CloudStorageAccount

Tags: java, azure-functions

I have a Java Azure Function. I would like build Service Bus triggered function with blob output. The Service Bus message is in JSON format. I would like to append content to CSV by hour.

I'm looking at an example for writing to blobs from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java-legacy), but getting an error on import. Any advice?

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount; // cannot be resolved.
```

ERROR:

```
package com.topictriggerdatalakeoutput;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount; // cannot be resolved.

/**
 * Azure Functions with Service Topic Trigger.
 */
public class TopicTriggerDatalakeOutput {
/**
 * This function will be invoked when a new message is received at the Service Bus Topic.
 */
@FunctionName("TopicTriggerDatalakeOutput")
public void run(
    @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
        name = "message",
        topicName = "MyTopic",
        subscriptionName = "MyTopicDataLakeSubscription",
        connection = "sbconnstring"
    )
    String message,

    final ExecutionContext context
) {

    String storageConnectionString = System.getenv("DataLakeconnstring");

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount; // cannot be resolved

    //blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
    //container = blobClient.getContainerReference("quickstartcontainer");

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the storage dependency to your **pom.xml** file. Then this error will be removed.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
    <version>8.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```